# Limit F5 (Run->Start Debugging) to language modes VS Code can execute

Tags: visual-studio-code

I sometimes mistakenly press F5 in a VS Code tab containing SQL code (mostly when my eyes are on the other screen looking at pgAdmin and not realizing that the focus is on the VS Code window). VS Code then launches a Python interpreter on my SQL code, failing of course.

I want to avoid this. Essentially I want F5 to be limited to editor tabs containing Python or other program code that VS Code is able to execute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a keybinding at the end of the `keybindings.json` file. It will set the action to do nothing on `F5` for a selection of languages

```
{
  "key": "F5",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "" },
  "when": "editorLangId == sql || editorLangId == plaintext"
}
```

Comment: I needed to correct the when clause, then it worked: `"editorLangId == sql || editorLangId == plaintext'`.

Comment: Curiously, for all languages not disabled by above keybinding the action seems to be to launch the Python interpreter. For example, pressing F5 in an editor tab containing Java code launches Python (which of course throws an error). Seems my VS Code installation has a more general problem.

Comment: @Robert, oops I program to much python, mixed Python and When operators, Do you have a Python launch config selected in the Debug Bar, F5 launches the current select config, it has nothing to do with the current languageID

Comment: Indeed, I have a Python launch configuration. The current project uses multiple languages: SQL, Bash, Python. What I want is the right launch configuration for the right file. This was requested in: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124877, and as documented there, implemented in following extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DarrenLevine.auto-debug.

Comment: @Robert you can use[Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) to create keybindings for `F5` to launch a config based on languageID of the current editor